# MOC3021 appropriate input resistance value for microcontroller application

Tags: arduino, resistance, opto-isolator

[image]

I have this design.
Mounted on "Project Board" and "Universal PCB" it works great.

But soldered in a specially designed PCB only works fine for the first 10 tries, every 2 seconds, high work load.

All 3 versions use same kind of componentes.

So... I tried to cut off the led attached at input (Led1), and the performance increased 20%, but again fails in 14th try.

It looks like a  saturation in moc3021.

I assume:

- R5 ( 220Ohms) is to high?
- R6 (1.5KOhms) is not needed?

Comment: Since the problem occurs on "specifically designed PCB", maybe it is reasonable to post the PCB layout? And maybe mention voltages ("CANTON...")you are trying to control with this opto-isolator?

Answer (score 2):

According to the datasheet MOC3021 requires 15mA at T=25 degree C to be sure of triggering. You should add some to that to account for aging and lower temperatures, so maybe 20mA.

If your microcontroller can safely source 20mA you can look at the minimum Vout(high) while sourcing 20mA to see what the resistor should be.

Otherwise, either use a transistor to drive the LED or use a more sensitive optocoupler.

Comment: I decided to don't use that led.  But problem remains.

Comment: Ando, sorry, I'm talking about the infrared LED in the optocoupler, not the indicator LED.

Answer (score 2):

You have approximately 16 mA through the MOC3021 LED, and another 8.5 mA through your indicator LED. This would seem to be much higher (25.5 mA) than I'd expect you should source from an MCU output pin.

As you draw current from an output pin the voltage will drop, and some heat will be dissipated in the device. While I'm not sure that this is your problem, you certainly can improve the situation.

Most MCU's will sink slightly more current than they will source, I'll use the [Atmega328p](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42735-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega328-328P_datasheet.pdf) as an example here:

Here is the output voltage versus source current and at 20 mA you lose about 0.55 V.
[image]

Here is the output voltage when you sink current and at 20 mA you lose about 0.45 V. 
[image]

This voltage loss will modify your currents slightly, but more importantly the current you are drawing is just too much.
I'd recommend that you could run both LEDs in series.

If the indicator LED is a RED LED then Vf is likely about 2.2 V, and the MOC3021 LED is at most 1.5 V. Setting the current to say 18 mA (the maximum for the MOC3021 at 0 degC) would mean a series resistor of about 72 Ohms.

You can see from the [MOC3021 datasheet](http://www.futurlec.com/LED/MOC3021a.shtml) that the current requirements do go up for lower temperatures or narrow pulse widths:
[image]

If your current levels go up beyond 20 mA I would use a buffer to drive the LEDs and provide isolation from the MCU I/O pin.

Comment: The question is, I have tested so much same design on universal pcb with no failures. Traslated to a printed circuit it fails. Why?
I will not use that led.

Comment: It could be minor variations in the power supply, a change in capacitance, or even the use of DIP vs TQFP om your PCB ....you don't give enough details to know.

Answer (score 0):

Remove R6, has no functionality more than to increase the current drawn from the MCU's D2 pin.

Calculate the value for R5. OK1 LED = 15mA and 1.25 volt.

R5 = (D2 voltage - OK1 LED Voltage)/OK1 LED current = (5v - 1.25v)/15mA

R5 = 250 ohm (so 220 ohm in the picture is spot on).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the printed circuit. It has a bad connection in a solder point and I solved using a cutter. 
Thats caused changes in resistance that affects the output voltaje.

Comment: You should probably explain a bit more what the problem was. You can also accept this answer to bring it to the top and guide the reader to the solution.